# convert very big json to sql using Ijson

Tags: python, json, multithreading, parsing, ijson

I have 60GB json file and i want to convert it to sql with ijson. ( i tried many software and tools , They weren't useful and my system was crashing.

**Note** : this is not duplicated ! i see all code about this methods and wrote this but still i have a very slow code .

here is my code :

```
import json
import sqlite3
import ijson 
import threading


def solve():
    with sqlite3.connect("filename.db") as conn:
        try:
            conn.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(
            username       VARCHAR(225) 
            ,phone         INTEGER   
            ,id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

            );''')
        except :
            pass
        keys = ["username", "phone" ,  "id"]
        with open('VERYBIGJSON.json' , 'r' , encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            data = ijson.parse(json_file ,  multiple_values=True)

            for prefix, event, value in data:
                if str(event) == 'start_map':
                    _u = None

                if prefix == "id" :
                    _id = value

                if prefix == "username":
                    _u = value

                if prefix == "phone":
                    _p = value

                try:
                    if  str(event) == 'end_map' :
                        values = (_u , _p , _id)
                        cmd = """INSERT INTO mytable (username , phone , id)  VALUES(
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?

                                );"""
                        conn.execute(cmd, values)



                        conn.commit()

                except Exception as e:
                    #print (str(e))
                    continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t=[]
    for i in range(1000):
        t.append(threading.Thread(target=solve))


    for i in t: 
        i.start() 

    for i in t:
        i.join()
```

i tested both multi threading and multi procesing method and still my code run very very slowly ! (**only  10KB of my sql database will generated per seconds** ).

I want to do it very effeceintly.

my json sample is :

```
{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"delete\":{\"test\":true},\"flags\":2067,\"id\":11111110,\"phone\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"photo\":{\"_\":\"userProfilePhoto\",\"photo_id\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"photo_small\":{\"_\":\"file\",\"dcs\":4,\"volume_id\":\"8788701\",\"local_id\":385526},\"photo\":{\"_\":\"file\",\"dcs\":4,\"local_id\":385528}},\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStat\",\"online\":1566173427}}","phone":"xxxxxxxxxx","@version":"1","id":11111110}
{"index": {"_type": "_doc", "_id": "-Lcy4m8BAObvGO9GAsFa"}}
```

....

Please give me an idea to improve the code speed.

**UPDATE:**
according to comments i wrote a code for converting my big json file to .csv but still it is so slow but faster than method 1!

here is code :

```
import json
import sqlite3
import ijson 
from multiprocessing import Process
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading

def solve():

        with open('VERYBIGJSON.json' , 'r' , encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            data = ijson.parse(json_file ,  multiple_values=True )

            for prefix, event, value in data:

                if str(event) == 'start_map':

                    _u = None




                if prefix == "id" :
                    _id = value

                if prefix == "username":
                    _u = value

                if prefix == "phone":
                    _p = value



                if  str(event) == 'end_map' :

                            values = [{'username':'{}'.format(_u) , 'id':'{}'.format(_id) , 'phone':'{}'.format(_p)}] #converting to json for add to 'json_normalize'


                            df = json_normalize(values)
                            df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, mode='a' ,  encoding='utf-8' , header=False)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve()
```

**Also with JsonSlicer library:**

```
def solve():


        with open('VERYBIGJSON.json' , 'r' , encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            for key   in JsonSlicer(json_file , (None , None) ) :
                print (key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve()
```

i Get this error:

```
    for key   in JsonSlicer(json_file , (None , None) ) :
RuntimeError: YAJL error: parse error: trailing garbage
          d_from":"telegram_contacts"} {"index": {"_type": "_doc", "_i
                     (right here) ------^
```

I think this library don't support my json file.

Comment: sqlite doesn't do well with concurrent writes, and committing for every row is likely to be slow -- you might do better to convert your json to csv and then use the sqlite `.import` special statement

Comment: i will add my method for converting json to .csv ( still it is very slow !)

Comment: I mean, you're dealing with parsing 6GB of json in python, it's not exactly going to be fast :)

Comment: yes but it is very very slow and my Json  size is 60GB

Comment: your update still suffers from the "many small writes" problem, try batching your writes in an append-only manner (you probably won't need pandas to do simple csv appends fwiw) -- but also I'm not sure why you expect doing anything with 60GB of data to be fast?

Comment: i also wroted it with JsonSlicer but i have problem with it